# Resolve promise in callback

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await

My client-websocket provides means to register callbacks for certain events, e.g. when the connection is opened or closed. Within these callbacks I want to resolve a promise so I can `await` the occurrence of the events from the outside. I use this in unit-tests. I want something like this:

```
let wsOnOpenPromise = new Promise<void>(resolve => { /* ??? */ });
let wsOnClosePromise = new Promise<void>(resolve => { /* ??? */ });
const ws = new WebsocketBuilder(url)
    .onOpen((i, e) => { /* resolve wsOnOpenPromise here */ })
    .onClose((i, e) => { /* resolve wsOnClosePromise here */ })
    .build();
await wsOnOpenPromise;
shutdownServer(); /* Shutdown the server here, the on-close event should fire */
await wsOnClosePromise;
```

How would I do this? It seems like I need to define the promises first and `resolve` them in the callbacks so I can later `await` them like shown in the code.

Comment: `resolve => { resolve() })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working like this:

```
let onOpen = () => {};
let onClose = () => {};
const wsOnOpenPromise = new Promise<void>(resolve => onOpen = resolve);
const wsOnClosePromise = new Promise<void>(resolve => onClose = resolve);
const ws = new WebsocketBuilder(url)
    .onOpen((i, e) => { onOpen() })
    .onClose((i, e) => { onClose() })
    .build();
await wsOnOpenPromise;
/* Shutdown the server here, the on-close event should fire */
await wsOnClosePromise;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
const ws = new WebsocketBuilder(url);
const onOpen = new Promise(ws.onOpen.bind(ws));
const onClose = new Promise(ws.onClose.bind(ws));
ws.build();
await onOpen;
shutdownServer(); /* Shutdown the server here, the on-close event should fire */
await onClose;
```

#### Explanation:

The following expression:

```
new Promise(ws.onOpen.bind(ws))
```

...is really similar to:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => ws.onOpen(resolve, reject))
```

As `onOpen` only takes one argument, `reject` doesn't really play a role. This can be further expanded to the equivalent:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => ws.onOpen((i, e) => resolve(i, e), reject))
```

Also here, `resolve` just takes one argument, so `i` will be the value the promise resolves with -- even though you are not really interested in it. That's why we can shorten all that to just:

```
new Promise(ws.onOpen.bind(ws))
```

The same principle goes for the `onClose`.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the good explanation! I appreciate it!!